# How to limit the timing that can be picked from Cupertino date picker in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, flutter-cupertino, cupertinopicker

Currently, this is how my Cupertino date picker look like

[image]

My code is as shown:

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
                      initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                      onDateTimeChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                          dateSelected = val;
                        });
                      })
```

How can I make it such that I only allow the user to pick timing after 6 pm and before 3 am, every day?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the built in widget, you could use this one https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_date_picker

Comment: I'd prefer to use the original cupertino package as it looks nicer. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot limit the timer. We can instead check if the current picked time is equal to our expectations. If not so show the user a dialog or a message to re enter the data and the current data entered is not available. Maybe this works for you.

Comment: Yup, that's a workaround I thought about as well. It ain't optimal but I shall stick to it for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
              CupertinoDatePicker(
                  maximumDate:...,// give it DateTime 
                  minimumDate:...,// give it DateTime
                  initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                  onDateTimeChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      dateSelected = val;
                    });
                  })
```